# How to define a region within a property in prism

Tags: wpf, prism

I have a ContentControl hosting a region, which is within a property. The problem is, prism does not find the region manager on this ContentControl.

```
<MyView>
   <MyView.Menu>
      <MyMenu>
         <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="AppBarRegion" />
      </MyMenu>
   </MyView.Menu>
</MyView>
```

Is there a way to fix this problem?

Thanks for help,
Eny

Answer (score 0):

Have you added any views to your region? If so, I am gathering from your question that you are just not seeing them when you run the app, well in your Unity Bootstrapper

```
protected override void InitializeModules ()
    {
        base.InitializeModules ();

        var manager = Container.Resolve<IRegionManager> ();
        var region = manager.Regions["AppBarRegion"];

        /*i am assuming you have added some views to your region :) */
        region.Activate (region.Views.FirstOrDefault ());
    }
```

Here's a sample link to prism application check list:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165376/A-Prism-4-Application-Checklist

Comment: Hi, no the region manager does not add the region, because it does not finde the parents region manager while processing the attached dependency property.
Your code will produce an exception, because there is no AppBarRegion available.

Comment: but you are creating it in xaml:  <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="AppBarRegion" />

Comment: Yes, within a property of the parent type and not within the content property, so the parent is not set in "MyMenu" :) Prism iterates thru the parents of an element until it finds the region manager or until it does not find any parent anymore, and that happens in my case.

Comment: what if you move it, just as a test, out of View.Menu, somewhere else, would that work?

Comment: No, unfortunatelly I cannot change the place I have to put the menu

Comment: the reason I am asking is, is it a part of the visual tree, if it isn't maybe that's why the manager, can't find it in its regions.

Comment: Mh thats a good hint, perhaps I can grab teh parent through the visual tree and not the object tree